# String.IndexOf() returns unexpected index of string

Tags: c#, .net, indexof

String.IndexOf() method is not acting as I expected.

I expected it not to find a match, since the exact word **you** is not in `str`.

```
string str = "I am your Friend";
int index = str.IndexOf("you",0,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Output: 5

My Expected Result is -1 because the string doesn't contain **you**.

Comment: You're asking for the position of the _sequence of characters_ "you" in the string, not the position of the _word_ "you" in the string. Since "your" starts with "you", we can conclude that the sequence of characters "you" is in the string. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) states _"Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a specified Unicode character or **string** within this instance. The method returns -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance."_

Comment: @bolkay Though `Contains()` will also conclude that "you" is in the string "I am your Friend".

Comment: I am **you**r Friend... looks like its in there to me.. if you need word boundaries use regex, or hack in spaces left and right of your search string (however will likely cause more issues)

Comment: I suspect that what you want to do is `string.Split` to split the string into words. Then `string.Compare` rather than `string.IndexOf`.

Comment: if you want to keep most of your code, you could search for " you " instead of "you" (just add spaces before and after your "you" string)

Comment: @Dle Would that work for searching for the initial `I`?

Comment: good point @mjwills didn't think about that, it wouldn't find a "closing" you neither

Comment: Ah, I got your meaning inverted. I get 5, and I expected 5. The string does definitly contain 'you'. It does not contain 'you ' however, but that's a different string.

Comment: yes, Davesoft you get it, indexof function searching containing a word, I mean "you" word is not exist in the string but still it will return index 5 results should be -1

Comment: I want to find a position of the perticular word , so from indexof function, I can get starting index, but an index of gives the wrong index

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because `IndexOf` matches a single character, or sequence of characters (a search string) within the greater string. Therefore "I am your friend" contains the sequence "you". To match words only, you have to consider things at a word level.

For example, you could use Regular Expressions' to match around the word boundaries:

```
private static int IndexOfWord(string val, int startAt, string search)
{
    // escape the match expression in case it contains any characters meaningful
    // to regular expressions, and then create an expression with the \b boundary
    // characters
    var escapedMatch = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(search));

    // create a case-sensitive regular expression object using the pattern
    var exp = new Regex(escapedMatch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // perform the match from the start position
    var match = exp.Match(val, startAt);

    // if it's successful, return the match index
    if (match.Success)
    {
        return match.Index;
    }

    // if it's unsuccessful, return -1
    return -1;
}

// overload without startAt, for when you just want to start from the beginning
private static int IndexOfWord(string val, string search)
{
    return IndexOfWord(val, 0, search);
}
```

In your example you would try to match `\byou\b`, which because of the boundary requirements won't match `your`.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/IGYC14201)

See more about word boundaries in Regular Expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 2):

`you` is a valid substring of `I am your Friend`. If you would like to find if a word is in a string you can [parse the string with Split method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
```

And then look inside the array. Or turn it into more lookup-friendly data structure.

If you would like to search case-insensitive you can use the following code:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
string text = "I am your Friend";
// HasSet allows faster lookups in case of big strings
var words = text.Split(delimiterChars).ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(words.Contains("you"));
Console.WriteLine(words.Contains("friend"));
```

> False
>   True

---

Creating dictionary as in the following code-snippet you can quickly check all positions for all words.

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
string text = "i am your friend. I Am Your Friend.";
var words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(words[i])) dict[words[i]].Add(i);
    else dict[words[i]] = new List<int>() { i };
}

Console.WriteLine("youR: ");
dict["youR"].ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", i));
Console.WriteLine("friend");
dict["friend"].ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", i));
```

> ```
> youR:   
>         2   
>         7   
> friend   
>         3   
>         8
> ```